# tbl_merge from gtsummary package - Error: All objects in 'tbls' must be class 'gtsummary'

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm trying to merge three regression tables (tbl_regression) using the tbl_merge function in the gtsummary package. I keep getting the error message: "All objects in 'tbls' must be class 'gtsummary'", but I cannot seem to find out how to solve the problem.

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: Please update your post with a reproducible example, aka a reprex, aka code we can all run on our machines

Comment: More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this issue in the future: I've seen this before when merging `tbl_summary()` output. Example tables below.

```
t_1 <-
    mtcars %>%
    filter(am == 1) %>%
    tbl_summary()

t_2 <-
    mtcars %>%
    filter(am == 0) %>%
    tbl_summary()
```

In my case, I had typed the following when I encountered the error:

```
tbl_merge(
  tbls = c(t_1, t_2),
  tab_spanner = c("**am == 1**", "**am == 0**")
)
```

however, as shown in the `tbl_merge` [documentation](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/gtsummary/html/tbl_merge.html), the `tbls=` argument must be a list as below.

```
tbl_merge(
  tbls = list(t_1, t_2),
  tab_spanner = c("**am == 1**", "**am == 0**")
)
```